# Update XML file using another XML file in C# Without Loops

Tags: c#, xml

I have two Xml files

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <RowNo>1</RowNo>
    <BatchMId>632</BatchMId>
    <RandomNo>513EHGPDX9GH</RandomNo>
    <ParentRandomNo>0000003</ParentRandomNo>
    <Status>6</Status>
    <AggregrationTimestamp>08/06/2017 1:07:28 </AggregrationTimestamp>
    <CommissioningTimestamp>06/06/2017 17:26:31</CommissioningTimestamp>
    <Grade>A</Grade>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <RowNo>2</RowNo>
    <BatchMId>632</BatchMId>
    <RandomNo>6S91XPK1Y8AV</RandomNo>
    <ParentRandomNo>0000004</ParentRandomNo>
    <Status>6</Status>
    <AggregrationTimestamp>08/06/2017 1:07:28 </AggregrationTimestamp>
    <CommissioningTimestamp>06/06/2017 17:26:31</CommissioningTimestamp>
    <Grade>A</Grade>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

**Change.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <RowNo>1</RowNo>
    <BatchMId>632</BatchMId>
    <RandomNo>513EHGPDX9GH</RandomNo>
    <ParentRandomNo>0000003</ParentRandomNo>
    <Status>5</Status>
    <AggregrationTimestamp>09/06/2017 11:07:28 </AggregrationTimestamp>
    <CommissioningTimestamp>09/06/2017 11:07:28</CommissioningTimestamp>
    <Grade>B</Grade>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

In the both files `<randomno>` is unique and both files are the same. Change.xml just has some element values that are updated.

And now I want to update Main.xml with these changes and need output like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <RowNo>1</RowNo>
    <BatchMId>632</BatchMId>
    <RandomNo>513EHGPDX9GH</RandomNo>
    <ParentRandomNo>0000003</ParentRandomNo>
    <Status>5</Status>
    <AggregrationTimestamp>09/06/2017 11:07:28 </AggregrationTimestamp>
    <CommissioningTimestamp>09/06/2017 11:07:28</CommissioningTimestamp>
    <Grade>B</Grade>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <RowNo>2</RowNo>
    <BatchMId>632</BatchMId>
    <RandomNo>6S91XPK1Y8AV</RandomNo>
    <ParentRandomNo>0000004</ParentRandomNo>
    <Status>6</Status>
    <AggregrationTimestamp>08/06/2017 1:07:28 </AggregrationTimestamp>
    <CommissioningTimestamp>06/06/2017 17:26:31</CommissioningTimestamp>
    <Grade>A</Grade>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

I have a minimum of 500000 records in this file and I want to update this xml file without using any loops in c#. If anyone has an idea about this, please let me know. I tried using a for loop but it takes much more time to update it.
So, if any one have an idea without loops then share with me.

Comment: Issue aside, why does it matter if you use loops or not? Loops are not inherently evil... If it's taking a long time it is possible it was the way you had them set up. Could you post the code you used?

Comment: First of all, show your code (with loops) and describe your problem (too long  execution time). And then we'll try to find where your problem is and/or propose solution which works

Comment: Then create a dictionary to make it quicker to located records.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175287/how-to-merge-two-xml-files)

Answer (score 0):

Try following to get dictionary :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication71
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, XElement> dict = doc.Descendants("Table").GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("RandomNo"), y => y).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code. Working Perfect. Source is your source set and change is in change set

```
DataSet changeSet = new DataSet();
changeSet.ReadXml("d:\\change.xml");
DataSet sourceSet = new DataSet();
sourceSet.ReadXml("d:\\source.xml");
sourceSet.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { sourceSet.Tables[0].Columns["ParentRandomNo"] };
changeSet.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { changeSet.Tables[0].Columns["ParentRandomNo"] };
try
{
    sourceSet.Merge(changeSet, false);
    sourceSet.AcceptChanges();
    sourceSet.WriteXml("d:\\updated.xml");
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```