# Wisely save and read changed configuration (stored in XML file)

Tags: xml, xpath, design-patterns

I'm dealing with a system which stores its configuration (in a broad sense) in XML files. It also enables overriding certain parameters by user. Right now if the configuration is changed by user **whole** XML file gets re-written (in user directory) with changes. It's however very inconvenient.

Let's imagine we have base configuration like:

```
<configuration>
    <groupOfProperties>
        <someProperty>Sample value</someProperty>
        <otherProperty>Sample other value</otherProperty>
    </groupOfProperties>
</configuration>
```

It got overridden by user and now changed one looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <groupOfProperties>
        <someProperty>Changed value</someProperty>
        <otherProperty>Sample other value</otherProperty>
    </groupOfProperties>
</configuration>
```

It's cool and problem-less, unless our base configuration changed for some reason. For example - a new parameter was added:

```
<configuration>
    <groupOfProperties>
        <someProperty>Sample value</someProperty>
        <otherProperty>Sample other value</otherProperty>
        <newProperty>Sample new value<newProperty>
    </groupOfProperties>
</configuration>
```

Now user is not aware of that change and some **black box** reading XML file won't get new attributes which got changed in base. We can safely assume however that fact of not reading some of them is fail-safe and it affect only functional layer of system.

Is there any way to **smartly** save changed XML (preferably - just changed part) and easily 'merge' it with base file while processing request to get certain value?

I would imagine that what I actually save is not an XML file, but rather some kind of patch (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5261). Then while reading certain attribute I would basically read base file and apply patch over it to get 'real' configuration?

I'm not looking for a very precise implementation, but rather a general solution to this problem and some conceptions how to solve it.

Many thanks for the answers!

P.S. In real system XML files are MUCH more complex than given examples.

P.S.2 Unluckily XML files (or any other flat files) are the only way to go for the system. We can call a tech-debt.

Comment: My first thought was XSLT and sure enough found a similar answer for a similar problem! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175287/how-to-merge-two-xml-files. I believe this would sort your issue? I'm a little unclear as to how your save works though... do you have access to the master file and the users file at the point you want to save? Regardless of the XSLT implmentation you want to be comparing the _new_ file to the _master_ file and only updating fields that are different - and XSLT is an elegant solution for this in my opinion

Comment: In mentioned system configuration is usually a dialog (UI element) definition & logic associated with user interaction with the dialog.  We provide some simple editor that can be used to modify its design & its behaviors. Once user decides to make change it's saved in changed form and once we recognize user context we display changed dialog (to simplify - changed XML file), not the master one. However at any time we have access to the master one. The file itself can be **really** complex and irregular and writing XSLT to transform every and each one of them is simply undoable I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution of capturing data changes as a series of patches is called [Event Sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html). It allows the current data state to be calculated by applying all previous patches, and also allows auditing of any previous state. The quintessential example of this pattern is a version control system.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! I do understand the concept of event sourcing. I do believe however that my problem is not to keep track of the events, store them, give possibility to undo them or use any other benefits coming from it. Mentioned XML files are static in application runtime. They are changed once (outside application runtime) and are not modified anyhow afterwards. So essentially my problem is how to smartly capture & apply that change.